Mirroring/reflection of long texts
I would like to write hints for exercises and to prevent the students from immediately glancing at the hints before trying the exercise themselves, I want to type the hints in a reflected way. I would like them to be reflected vertically so that you cannot simply turn the page to look at them but you additionally have to stand in front of a mirror in order to read it.
I was able to do this thanks to some other online resources by using the raisebox command.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewEnviron{hint}
{%
\noindent 
\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\BODY}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{hint}
Lorem ipsum
\end{hint}

\end{document}

The result is what I wanted it to be (see below).

The problem arises when I add more text: the text that I type in the hint environment does not break automatically. The result is that if I insert a long text (longer than one line), it just tries to fit it all in one line and runs of the page (see picture below).
\begin{hint}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam aliquam vestibulum nunc, nec finibus elit malesuada vitae. Curabitur a efficitur nisl, nec sodales quam. Quisque molestie malesuada nisi in tempor. Donec in ultrices lectus. Nam scelerisque, sem at placerat vehicula, felis justo iaculis lacus, eget porttitor ante velit in velit.
\end{hint}


Does anyone have any idea as to how I can fix this?
Thanks in advance!

\scalebox{1}[-1]{\parbox{7cm}{\BODY}}

For comparison: \vbox can be used in OpTeX:
\fontfam[lm]

\def\hint#1{\par
   \transformbox{\pdfscale{1}{-1}}{\vbox{\noindent{\bf Hint:} #1}}
   \medskip
}

\lorem[1]
\hint{\lorem[5]}

\lorem[3]
\bye


Use a bottom aligned \parbox. I'd also add some vertical space to separate the hint from the running text.
No need to use environ nowadays.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{+b}
  {%
   \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}
   \noindent\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{#1}}}%
   \par\addvspace{\smallskipamount}
  }
  {}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{hint}
Lorem ipsum
\end{hint}

\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{hint}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{hint}

\lipsum[4][1-4]

\end{document}


